# Change colors in GRUB2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, colors

I have a dualboot setup,but I cannot see how to change some color.
I keep getting the black and grey stuff.

If I change some line in the grub.cfg file and when I do update-grub it reverts back to black.
The only thing that the graphical GRUB customizer was able to do is change the default boot order and sound a beep. It can do nothing about the colors!

I can not really read Ruby if that is what it is.
Where can I comment something out or put a line in that let's me see some effect?

Comment: `update-grub` re-creates the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file, which is the intention of the command. Changes should generally be made in `/etc/grub.d/` & `/etc/default/grub` which contains configs that are used to create grub.cfg  (*at the top of grub.cfg it tells you that too, yes it says `grub-mkconfig` but that's the command that `update-grub` uses to create the grub.cfg file*)   You didn't provide OS & release details

Comment: It was ubuntu from yesterday. 20.4 I think. And windows 10on a HP Spectre laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what to be expected since `update-grub` will overwrite your just edited `grub.cfg`.

Instead of editing `grub.cfg` you should change some lines in `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`. Look for the lines

```
set_default_theme(){
    case $GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR in
        Tanglu|Ubuntu|Kubuntu)
            # Set a monochromatic theme for Tanglu/Ubuntu.
            echo "${1}set menu_color_normal=white/black"
            echo "${1}set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray"
```

and adapt them according to your needs. Then run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: thanks, I will try that later..also try'd the following from another post. That worked also. because he named it default.grub? anyway..spend also a half houer because I misspelled the shebang. #!/bin/bash

file=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.grub

touch $file
echo "if background_color 66,30,53 ; then
   clear
fi" > $file

update-grub